# How to connect to database with logged in windows user in asp.net intranet web application?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, database-connection, intranet

we are migrating existing windows form application to asp.net(3.5) intranet portal, there is a requirement whereby database connection should be made by the logged in windows user.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality?

can someone please help me?

Comment: Is the DB on the same server as the web server? Multi-hop impersonation I've found sometimes is a little tricky. However, if you search for "asp.net impersonation" and "multi-hop asp.net impersonation" you should be able to find enough to get you going.

Comment: no, db server is different to webserver.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set impersonation in web.config file of your web application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx